# Append Tag into Outlook Subject field with user editable variable

Tags: vba, outlook

Our CRM requires a tag to be placed into the subject field of incoming/outgoing e-mail consisting of `<TaskID=xxxx>` or `<TicketID=xxxx>` whereby xxxx is a generated number from our CRM.

Does any know if it's possible to create either 1 or 2 Ribbon 'buttons' within Outlook to append this tag to the subject line. Ideally I'd like a dialog box to appear when you click this box so that you can type in the Ticket or Task ID which will then also be appended into the tag as per above.

I gather the first step is quite easy, but not having a great deal of exposure to VB means I'm a bit stuck with a dialog box and then putting the entry into the subject also.

Any help would be very much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Select the message and then run this code:

```
Sub SetSubjectCRM()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim obj As Object
Dim msg As Outlook.mailItem
Dim response As Variant
Dim subjectPart As String
Dim tickettype As String

Set obj = ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)

If TypeName(obj) = "MailItem" Then
  Set msg = ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)
End If

With msg
  ' get CRM number and type
  subjectPart = InputBox("What is the CRM number for this email? Enter 'TaskID' or 'TicketID'")

  ' parse response
  response = Split(subjectPart, ",")
  subjectPart = response(0)
  tickettype = response(1)

  .Subject = msg.Subject & " <" & tickettype & "=" & subjectPart & ">"

  .Save
End With

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

You need to enter the input as follows:

CRM Number,TaskID/TicketID

Example:

**12345,TaskID**

or

**13245,TicketID**

Assign the code to a QAT button like this:

http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/macrobutton.htm